# How can I get in contact with an Ubuntu developer who can give me advise for my software project?

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I'm working on an open source space shooter called orxonox. (www.orxonox.net)
Since the Ubuntu 12.04 release we faced a problem that we couldn't fix which is related to the upstream library tinyXML or Cegui ( http://forum.orxonox.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=660 ).

That bug is blocking our upcoming release. I'd be grateful if I can find someone who could be a mentor for both targeting the bug and the release process.

Comment: Should that not be filed as a bug on the package maintainers lauchpad.net tracker? Or you mean really contact the developers of the libs?

Comment: Guys, I think he wants help on getting the fix into Ubuntu, and shipped to 12.04 as an SRU.

Comment: I would like to get in contact with someone who could help me fix the bug. Where could I find developers? Or does anyone know someone personally who could help me?

Answer (score 1):

I see `cegui` is a Ubuntu Universe package.

First I think you should report the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cegui-mk2). We generally refer people to [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for help in filing bugs.

Second, you should check upstream ([Debian](http://packages.qa.debian.org/c/cegui-mk2.html) and [cegui.org.uk](http://www.cegui.org.uk/mantis/my_view_page.php)) to see if there is already a bug report for the bug you are seeing.

If there isn't already a fix it would be most effective if you could develop a patch for the package to fix the problem, or at least diagnose it as thoroughly as possible. If you can come up with a patch you can attach it to each of the bug reports. Getting upstream to accept the patch or develop one may convince the Ubuntu MOTU team that the patch is good.

See [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Sponsorship/SponsorsQueue) for the procedure to get the patch sponsored into Ubuntu Universe for the current development release. It's still not too late to get some patches into Ubuntu Universe for 12.10 but soon will be as its release is imminent. Getting a patch or new release into the development release is usually the first step in getting it into older releases (for reasons of quality assurance).

The MOTU team hangs out at irc://irc.freenode.net/#ubuntu-motu.